Truncation of $C^k$ functions in $C^k$
When we truncate a function $f$ we usually consider $g_n(x)=f(x)\mathbb{1}_{[-n,n]}(x)+f(n)\mathbb{1}_{(n,\infty)}(x)+f(-n)\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,-n)}(x)$, where $n$ is a natural number. Can we do it differently (in a standard, non case-to-case way) so that if $f\in C^k$, we get $g_n\in C^k$ such that $g_n=f$ if $x\in [-n,n]$ and $g_n$ is bounded outside $[-n,n]$?

Sure, take any $\phi_n\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ with $\phi_n(x)=1$ for all $x\in[-n,n]$ and consider $g_n=f\phi_n$. Then $g\big\vert_{[-n,n]}=f\big\vert_{[-n,n]}$, $g_n\in C^k(\mathbb{R})$, and $g_n(x)=0$ for all sufficiently big $\lvert x\rvert$

It really just amount to multiplying with a smooth enough bump function

@Lorago Shouldn't $\phi$ be $C^k$ to to ensure the product is $C^k$? For arbitrary $k$, how do I show such $\phi$ exists?

@Lorago this is not exactly what's asked here: the question is about smoothly extend $f$ by the a constant beyond $n$ (and $-n$). This not always possible.

@Falcon By 'differently' I meant 'a variation of it' so it is fine to relax the 'constant outside $[-n,n]$ feature, as I see why that would be an obstacle beyond mere continuity. Apologies for the confusion.

By searching 'bump functions' as suggested I found a standard construction that is constant $1$ on compacts and smoothens out to 0 outside a bigger compact, so it is actually possible to do it in $C^\infty$ as well. Thank you all for your help and the suggestions that lead me to find the right resources.

Whoops, typo on my part, I meant $\phi_n\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$
